# jQuery map selected object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with JavaScript,  could you help me please
Here is my problem.
I have this object:

```
var MyObj= [{ a: 0, b: "Zero", c: "x", d: "!" }, { a: 1, b: "One", c: "y", d: "@" }]
```

I want to change the element of selected object ("a" --> "id") to become like this:

```
var NewObj= [{ id: 0, b: "Zero", c: "x", d: "!" }, { id: 1, b: "One", c: "y", d: "@" }]
```

I tried to use $.map() method like this

```
NewObj= $.map(MyObj, function (obj) {
        return { id: obj.a, b: obj.b, c: obj.c, d:obj.d };
    });
```

Is there any better way to do this since I only change one element of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for ES6 / Object.assign, no need for jQuery:

**Working Fiddle**: https://jsbin.com/gosaqid/edit?js,console

```
function makeObj(obj){
  return obj.map(function(el, i) {
    el.id = i;
    delete el.a;
    return el;
  });
}
```

Comment: This is destructive, and will change `MyObj`. You might as well use `forEach` rather than `map`.

Comment: help me understand... isnt that what he wants? to change the object?

Comment: I assume, by his choice of variable names, that he wants to make a new object (`NewObj`) that is distinct from his old one (`MyObj`).

Comment: I assumed the opposite based on this: "I want to change the element of selected object ("a" --> "id") to become like this:"

Comment: @Omarjmh: Thank you very much, the code works. This is what i want.

Answer (score 2):

In your example `MyObj` is an *array of objects*.

```
var object = {}
var array = []
var arrayOfObjects = [{}, {}, {}]
```

In your desired result, you have changed one of the **keys** of *every object* in the array.

Using `map` is a perfectly adequate way of doing this, in fact JavaScript's array has a built in map method.

```
var newArrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.map(function (obj) {
  return {
    id: obj.a,
    b: obj.b,
    c: obj.c
  }
})
```

If you have a ton of keys this can get a little verbose so you can use `$.extend`, but chances are you're writing code for modern browsers so the whole thing can be written as such:

```
var newArrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.map(obj => 
  Object.assign({}, obj, { id: obj.a })
)
```

update: as @Amadan suggests, you can also delete the old key if you need

Answer (score 2):

Not unless you have a clone/copy/extend function available. One is [coming up](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.assign) in new JavaScript, and [jQuery has one](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), and it's not very hard writing your own. But it still isn't a walk in the park - you can't just rename a property, you need to copy and delete:

```
NewObj = MyObj.map(function(obj) {
  var newobj = Object.assign({}, obj, {id: obj.a});
  delete newobj.a;
  return newobj;
});
```